# How do i put a condition on a delete command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

i have a delete command:

```
DELETE FROM exam WHERE excode = '2';
```

But i need it to somehow reference another table and not delete it if the excode 2 exists in that table.

i have been looking at this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-delete.html

and this looks like something close to what i need to understand:

```
DELETE FROM films
WHERE producer_id IN (SELECT id FROM producers WHERE name = 'foo');
```

would love some help

Comment: Your link is to a *very* old version of the manual. Read the current manual for your version - which you should have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding this is what you want:

```
DELETE FROM exam WHERE excode = '2' and not exists (select * from table2 where excode = '2')
```

The syntax is for SQL Server but I think you could use it with no change.

If this is not what you want, explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could very well do it by using a query like this ,taking first table as you mentioned as "exam(excode)" and second table as "excodeTable(excode)"

```
DELETE FROM exam 
WHERE excode NOT IN(SELECT excode from excodeTable where excode='2')
```

If you want to check both the tables for the values i.e. excode=2 in first table and if excode=2 exists in second table also, then don't delete. For this you would have to use JOIN and use AND condition

Answer (score 0):

You can't use inner join on delete statements in postgres, but you can use "using" that does exactly the same and it's the optimal solution:

```
DELETE FROM films USING producers
  WHERE producer_id = producers.id AND producers.name = 'foo';
```

source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-delete.html